# the old version python 2.7 is persisting after upgrading to 3.7

Tags: python

I upgraded Ubuntu to the latest version and also python (2.7 to 3.7). When I type

> python --version

in the console I get the old version. Did the upgrading of python went wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/): The Python standard (which Debian and Ubuntu follow) is for the `python` command to point to Py2, never to Py3.

Answer (score 1):

The `python` package is the package for Python 2.x versions. Python 3's package information is in `python3`. To view its version info, you can do the same syntax; `python3 --version`.

**I recommend against uninstalling Python 3.** Even though you never explicitly said you were going to, I'm forewarning you, it is a *bad* thing to do.

Comment: I would say it more strongly: Uninstalling Py3 will definitely break any Ubuntu system after 2014 quite horribly.

Comment: I almost actually did it myself not that long ago, I'm slightly embarrassed to admit. It's a really good thing I checked up on it before I did anything I'd regret.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x and Python 3.x is not compatible. There's a lot of minor changes to syntax and built-in functions.

However, some scripts in Ubuntu is written for Python 2.7. They commonly have only `#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar as their interpreter in the script, so they rely on Python 2 being `python`. Many Python 3 scripts, otoh, call `python3`, so Python 2.7 and 3 can co-exist on the same system.

To use 3.x, run `python3`.

Example from a machine running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
[~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
[~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

Leave it as is. Changing it, may, as hinted by [EarthToAccess' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135615/) lead to less desireable outcomes, including fundamentally broken core system functions.